# Swann DVR8-3000 - Mobile port setup

Tags: home-networking, mobile-phone, dvr

Recently bought a Swann DVR8-3000 security camera kit for the house. I have it set up, working fine over the network, great.

I am trying to set it up so I can view camera's over my mobile phone, using Swann's SwannView app (from the Android Market).

The problem is, most instructions refer to a 'Mobile Port', which is meant to be in the DVRs Network setup options, or as a subheading under Devices. However, my DVR doesn't have this option (though I've been assured this product supports mobile access). The only ports I can setup in the Network Settings are HTTP Port (85 default) and Network Port (9000 default).

I am using Swanns DynDSN (swanndvr.net) to access the DVR (This setup has been tested, and apparently works). I've set up a user name and password for access, which works fine over network. uPnP is enabled on my router. The only thing I am not sure on is the 'mobile port'.

Does anyone have any information on what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "IP Camera viewer" from the Android Market by Robert Chow which sets up perfectly and easily. Select your DVR model from the drop down menus, it automatically selects port 9000. I allowed UpNP to open ports 85 and 9000. the DVR uses a static address so it doesn't change. I enter the actual address for our office and it opens fast and tracks ok, expensive/crappy TWC speeds aside. I'm also not using any DNS service.

The Swann viewer is not as good (I've read) as the IP Camera viewer which is excellent. I have used this program for a Foscam camera I have. I'm using Swann's program on my computers that I monitor the DVR remotely with, but am looking for an alternative. It keeps switching my desktop schemes to "Basic" and the list of prerecorded times is ridiculously small. Swann's software leaves me much to be desired.